# Why are functions within a stored procedure identified as dependencies but not stored procedures called from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, dependencies

I am currently carrying out some impact analysis on our SQL Server database in preparation for a scope of work I have been handed.

I am currently listing all dependencies on all objects I am identifying to be included in the scope of work.

One table has a trigger which includes a scalar function and a stored procedure. When I view the dependencies I don't see the stored procedure.

I'd like to better understand why this is and if there is a better way to work this out so nothing is missed?

Can someone help a junior out please?

Comment: +1 good question, but you don't need to sign your posts

Comment: point taken, yeah I'm not sure how to ensure nothing is missed due to the nature of this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should show you the references you are looking for.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name, 
    o.type_desc AS referencing_desciption, 
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referencing_minor_id, 
    referencing_class_desc, referenced_class_desc,
    referenced_server_name, referenced_database_name, referenced_schema_name,
    referenced_entity_name, 
    COALESCE(COL_NAME(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') AS referenced_column_name,
    is_caller_dependent, is_ambiguous
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'{THEOBJECTNAME}');
```

see: [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx)

Comment: I thought there would have been some clever way to utilise the system objects but lack the knowledge and understanding of where to start implementing my findings but that worked a treat! XD cheers...

Comment: if you run a sql trace and then click the view dependencies you can see what they are doing under the covers.  It is quite complicated but it looks like it is actually making a call to sys.sql_expression_dependencies but I don't understand fully why it doesn't pick up the sprocs called by a trigger?

Comment: I know weird right!?  Those little tricks I'm looking for to tool my personal knowlede base with.  I shall keep that in mind.  Thanks again.